# Zurb Foundation top bar menu on iPhone issue

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a Zurb Foundation 3 navigation menu. When the page is on a phone, it correctly shows the phone version of my menu system.

However, the only way to activate the menu is to tap the down=arrow triangle on the right.  I want to have the title also be active.

**EDIT:**  Added [this link](http://designbymgc.com/test/) to a simple working version of the home page.

*Notice, tapping the bar or the word "menu" highlights the bar, but only the arrow makes the menu appear.*

I am hiding the name ("Menu") on the desktop and showing it on the phone like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="contain-to-grid">
    <nav class="top-bar">
      <ul>
        <!-- Title Area -->
        <li class="name show-for-small">
          <h1><a href="#">Menu</a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
      </ul>

      <section>
        <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
               etc.
```

Since I expect a lot of people will tap on the title "menu" to access the menu I want to make it do the same as tapping the arrow on the right.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it. But I think you should look that which CSS class/id is responsible for showing the Menu. and apply that same class/id to "Menu".

Comment: i tried that first, but it then sticks the word menu flush right, same size and position as the arrow.

Comment: Then look for the function that reveals the menu in foundation libraries in the Javascript files, and apply that function to the Menu. "onlick=functionToRevealMenu()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you adjust:

```
.top-bar ul > li.toggle-topbar {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
```

and change the width value to:

```
width 100%;
```

It will work - in your app.css add:

```
.top-bar ul > li.toggle-topbar {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS method is one way, but I would up modifying jquery.foundation.topbar.js, line 45 (which is the function below) I changed `'.top-bar .toggle-topbar` to `'.top-bar .toggle-topbar, .top-bar .title'`

```
$('.top-bar .toggle-topbar, .top-bar .title').off('click.fndtn').on('click.fndtn', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (methods.breakpoint()) {
          settings.$topbar.toggleClass('expanded');
          settings.$topbar.css('min-height', '');
        }

        if (!settings.$topbar.hasClass('expanded')) {
          settings.$section.css({left: '0%'});
          settings.$section.find('>.name').css({left: '100%'});
          settings.$section.find('li.moved').removeClass('moved');
          settings.index = 0;
        }
      });
```